# SyntaxError: missing ] after element list when using setInterval

Tags: javascript

Running the following:

```
setTimeout(this.nextScene.load(function() {
    this.nextSceneLoaded = true;
}.bind(this)), 0);
```

is supposed to do load the next scene asynchronously and let us know when it's done, but I'm noticing "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list" in the Firefox console.

A bit of searching around StackOverflow has similar questions but they seem to involve people not using functions as the first argument to setTimeout.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it / are there any alternatives?

(Also no jQuery, etc. I'd like to keep this as much plain JavaScript as possible.)

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the error? That doesn't look like what the error is describing...

Comment: Remove `;` from `this.nextSceneLoaded = true` line

Comment: Does `this.nextScene.load` return a function?

Comment: Looks like the `load` function is async, as it uses a callback, and if so, this makes very little sense?

Comment: This code is fine. The error is in the nextScene.load function.

Comment: The console should tell you at what line the error occurs. Look around there. The problem may be due to the data you are loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to David Bradshaw for making me realise I wasn't passing a function into setTimeout (5am coding is a bad idea). What I was really trying to do was:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.nextScene.load(function() {
        this.nextSceneLoaded = true;
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this), 0);
```

However as other users have pointed out this really isn't helpful and still blocks the UI. Hopefully this'll be useful if anyone comes looking for something similar in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to do setTimeout and pass it 0 as the second value is to overcome a couple of obscure browser race conditions.

The code you have here calls this.nextScene with a callback and passes the result of that call to setTimeout, it is not delaying the execution and as your not passing the function by reference bind isn't doing anything here for you unless this.nextScene passes back a function.

My best guess at what your trying to do is this.

```
setTimeout(this.nextScene.load.bind(this, function(){
    this.nextSceneLoaded = true;
},0);
```